# ".findOneAndUpdate()" not updating database properly (Mongodb & Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I try to use `.findOneAndUpdate()` to update my database.

No error message, but this part of the database is not updated with new data. The embedded document `competitorAnalysisTextData` is still empty.

```
// on routes that end in /users/competitorAnalysisTextData
// ----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/users/competitorAnalysisTextData/:userName')

// update the user info (accessed at PUT http://localhost:8080/api/users/competitorAnalysisTextData)
.post(function(req, res) {

    console.log('1');

// Just give instruction to mongodb to find document, change it;
// then finally after mongodb is done, return the result/error as callback.
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userName : req.params.userName},
    {
        $set:
        {   "competitorAnalysis.firstObservation" : req.body.firstObservation,
            "competitorAnalysis.secondObservation" : req.body.secondObservation,
            "competitorAnalysis.thirdObservation" : req.body.thirdObservation,
            "competitorAnalysis.brandName" : req.body.brandName,
            "competitorAnalysis.productCategory" : req.body.productCategory
        }
    },
    { upsert: true },
    function(err, user) {
        // after mongodb is done updating, you are receiving the updated file as callback
        console.log('2');
        // now you can send the error or updated file to client
        if (err)
            return res.send(err);

        return res.json({ message: 'User updated!' });
    });

})
```

**Update**

This is my "User" Schema part:

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Require the crypto module for password hash
'use strict';
var crypto = require('crypto');

// create competitorAnalysisSchema
var CompetitorAnalysis = new Schema({
    firstObservation: { type: String },
    secondObservation: { type: String },
    thirdObservation: { type: String },
    brandName: { type: String },
    productCategory: { type: String }
});
// create competitorAnalysisPhotoSchema
var CompetitorAnalysisPhoto = new Schema({
    photo1: {type: String},
    photo2: {type: String},
    photo3: {type: String},
    photo4: {type: String}
});
// create UserSchema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    userName: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    currentDemo: { type: String },
    nextDemo: { type: String },
    startTime: { type: String },
    startLocation: { type: String },
    arriveTime: { type: String },
    arriveLocation: { type: String },
    leaveTime: { type: String },
    leaveLocation: { type: String },
    competitorAnalysis: [CompetitorAnalysis],
    competitorAnalysisPhoto: [CompetitorAnalysisPhoto],
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
});

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: maybe you can show the schema, i'm pretty sure the problem is not in the query

Comment: @vdj4y I've updated my post and show the schema. (Thank you so much!!)

Comment: competitorAnalysis contain array, at what index do you want to update?

Comment: @vdj4y I try to use dot "." to specify the element I want to update. e.g. "competitorAnalysis.firstObservation"?

Comment: @vdj4y Currently, the array is all empty. From the console: "competitorAnalysisPhoto" : [ ],
 "competitorAnalysis" : [ ],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript if you wish to update an object inside an array, you need to pick the index

```
var arr = [{name: "person1"},{name:"person2"}]
arr[0].name = "myname"
arr[1].name = "myFriend"
```

---

So it's the same in mongodb, check this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) for detail example, or you can manually input the index, for quick hack.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { userName : req.params.userName},
  {
    $set:
    {   "competitorAnalysis.0.firstObservation" : req.body.firstObservation,
        "competitorAnalysis.0.secondObservation" : req.body.secondObservation,
        "competitorAnalysis.0.thirdObservation" : req.body.thirdObservation,
        "competitorAnalysis.0.brandName" : req.body.brandName,
        "competitorAnalysis.0.productCategory" : req.body.productCategory
    }
  },
  { upsert: true },
  function(err, user) {
    // after mongodb is done updating, you are receiving the updated file as callback
    console.log('2');
    // now you can send the error or updated file to client
    if (err)
        return res.send(err);

    return res.json({ message: 'User updated!' });
  });

})
```

---

You should use the code above to update nested-array not to add to empty-array.
In javascript, if an array is still **empty**, we use .push() to add,  while in mongodb the command is [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

```
var arr = []
arr.push({name:"person1"})
```

Comment: Amazing instruction!